# Inside a click event, fire code once on first click, remaining code runs on all clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I run a piece of code only on the first click of a button but also have the remaining code run on all clicks?

```
$button.click(function (e) {
    // Only run on first click
    $element.removeClass('mobile').addClass('desktop');
    // Run on every click   
    $elementTwo.show()
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a Boolean flag variable

```
var st = true;
$button.click(function(e) {
  // this line only execute once, since after first execution `st` will update to false
  st && $element.removeClass('mobile').addClass('desktop') && st = false;
  $elementTwo.show()
});
```

Comment: Thanks. If you want to execute more than one statement on only the first click... In what way would you amend this?

Comment: @JP : you can use `if(st){//........ ; st=false;}` or all line of code returns a truthy value then use  `&&` between them

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [**one()**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method:

```
$button.one('click', function() { //this will run only on the first click
  $element.removeClass('mobile').addClass('desktop');
});

$button.click(function() {  //this will run for every click
  $elementTwo.show();
});
```